# How do I store a value from MySQL Database into variable?

Tags: java, sql, return

This question may be very easy, but I´m not exactly sure, how to do this.
I want to store the return value from my SQL-statement in a variable.

```
int i;
String name = "Testuser";
```

First i create my var. Now I want to store the value, which is saved in my Database **(named Data)** in a field called **"money"** , with the key "Testuser" into my variable i.

Comment: EDIT : I forgot to say, my key is a String field. Please check my edited post

Comment: Don't forget to ___accept an answer___ when it answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you have already the instance of statement you can do something like that

```
   int i;
ResultSet resultat = null;
   resultat = statement.executeQuery("SELECT money FROM data WHERE id=1;");//for example the value of the field money in the row who has id=1
   if(resultat.next()){ // you check if the query returned a value
 i=resultat.getInt("money"); // the name of the column
}
```